# Put a Firefox window in full screen mode

Tags: javascript

I've projected an Intranet Ajax application and I want put it in
a full screen mode so it seems as a real stand alone application.

My problem is that with Firefox 3 the `window.open` with options to
put the window in full screen mode not work well. I have always
the tile bar the url bar and the status bar.

Is there a way to hide that bars?

I remember not well that there is a way to write a script in a
signed way that the user can accept that.......

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible at all, if it were, it would be a huge security risk, phishing scams would be much more successful.

To get a more real feeling of a standalone app, maybe you should take a look at [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozilla.com) to use as client for your ajax web app.

Comment: Yes but in my LAN I wish to do that and also If use netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege(”UniversalBrowserWrite”);
my Firefox 3 tell me that there is no permission to execute that...so now I'll post a specific question about that.

Comment: I found a good solution and post it in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023644/firefox-and-universalbrowserwrite-privilege (my other similar question!)