# Firefox and UniversalBrowserWrite privilege

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I try to write:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
```

Firefox 3 tell me that to my script have been negated the UniversalBrowserWrite privileges!

Now I want to execute in my LAN a program that is maximized in a fullscreen mode and I want to use privileged statements for the windows as `toolbar=no` etc. but how can I do that?

I remember that when we use the statement above to the user will be prompeted a window that
tell it to accept a privileged script but now that window does not show.

I hope I must not set some about:config because my program must run into a LAN and I should deploy that configuration to all the client.

Comment: you CAN set about:config via a remote configuration. Do a little searching for how.

Comment: oh yeah, it's called AutoConfig (http://codeidol.com/internet/firefox/Installation/Remotely-Manage-User-Configurations/)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found this solution:

First we must in about:config setting this:

1) signed.applets.codebase_principal_support" to true
   to allow the execution of

```
 netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
```

and to show the user a confirmation window to allow that execution

2) "dom.disable_window_open_feature.location" to false
   to allow to hide the location bar

3) "dom.disable_window_open_feature.status" to false'
   to allow to hide the status bar

So code like this will put Firefox in a real full screen:

window.onload = function() 
    {

```
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
    var newWin = window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'so', 'dialog=yes,minimizable=no,personalbar=no, directories=no, titlebar=no, location=no');
};
```

After in the LAN we should set for the clients that about:config preferences and we can use a remote tool like suggested by SpliFF.

Comment: Brilliant — upvoted. Please note that directories is obsolete since Gecko 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think UniversalBrowserWrite can only be set if the call comes from a chrome window which has itself a chrome window as parent

Maybe the [R-kiosk addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1659) does the right thing for you