# Changing history entries in Firefox Browser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history

Firefox has a security privilege called `UniversalBrowserRead`, with which I'm able to read the history entries of the current window. There's also a `UniversalBrowserWrite`, but I couldn't use it to change history entries, like:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
for(var i = 0; i < history.length; i++)
  history[i]='http://www.google.com';
```

Does anyone know how to make it work (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need UniversalXPConnect to modify the history that way.

Note that enablePrivilege is deprecated and being slowly removed, so I wouldn't write new code depending on it...

Answer (score 0):

When I Google'd for 'netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");' this was the third result:

[Firefox and UniversalBrowserWrite privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023644/firefox-and-universalbrowserwrite-privilege)

Comment: I have seen this one, which has nothing to do with changing history entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't...

http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/js12/scripts.htm

In the table 'JavaScript Features Requiring Privileges'

> history object:
>
> Getting the value of any property <=>UniversalBrowserRead
>
> Setting the **preference** property <=> UniversalBrowserWrite

It says you can change preference, not value.

Answer (score 0):

the best you can do in javascript is change the last entry using location.replace()