# Close icon and window.open : feasibility and handling

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am putting up a new window like so:

```
var myWindow = window.open('', "RWindow", "dialog=yes, close=no, height=900, width=1400, top=70");
```

I have modified the relevant configuration parameters of the user agent (Firefox 58.0.1) —refer to: [Firefox and UniversalBrowserWrite privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023644/firefox-and-universalbrowserwrite-privilege)

Mozilla window.open API ( 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features )
specifies a **close** feature (that requires a privilege):

```
When set to no or 0, this feature removes the system close command icon and system close menu item. It will only work for dialog windows (dialog feature set). close=no will override minimizable=yes.
```

to no avail for me (please see the code quoted hereabove). What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Opening a new window is generally bad UI design, just saying...

Comment: my question is about facts, not opinions.